# NvLink or PCIe, how to specify the interconnect?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

My cluster is equipped with both Nvlink and PCIe. All the GPUs(V100) can communicate directly through both PCIe or NvLink. To my knowledge, both PCIe switch and Nvlink can support the direct link through using CUDA.

Now, I want to compare the peer-to-peer communication performance of PCIe and NvLink. However, I don't know how to specify one, it seems CUDA will always automatically specify one. Could anyone help me?

Comment: If you have NVLink connectivity between 2 GPUs, and you place those 2 GPUs into a P2P relationship, and do transfers between them, those transfers will flow over NVLink.  It is not possible to force those transfers to flow over PCIe instead.  If you want the transfers to flow over PCIe, then you will need to disable the P2P mode between those two devices.  In that case, the transfer will flow across PCIe, all the way through the CPU socket.  It will not flow directly across PCIe (switch) only.   Those are the only 2 choices you have.

Comment: The `p2pBandwidthLatencyTest` CUDA sample code demonstrates both modes of operation (P2P enabled, P2P disabled).  You may wish to study it.

Comment: Thank you very much, you verify my guess. I am an HPC developer and new to GPU. 
If I still want to use P2P with PCIe, I guess: Firstly, I can edit the configuration of the cluster and I have tried to contact the technical support. Secondly, can I slightly rewrite CUDA to make NvLink rank second? Is that difficult?

Comment: You can't do either one of those.

Comment: Coz the V100 is Nvlink version, the PCIe P2P is disabled in hardware level. Is my guess right......?

Comment: The capability to modify this behavior is not exposed to the end-user.   NVLink is a better GPU-GPU communication path (faster) than PCIE,  and so there is no reason to allow the end-user to choose the slower path.  It's not a configurable option.  There is no configuration file you can change, and there is nothing you can rewrite in CUDA that will make this work.

Comment: Many thanks to your patience

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If two GPUs in CUDA have a direct NVLink connection between them, and you enable Peer-to-Peer transfers, those transfers will flow over NVLink.  There is no method of any kind in CUDA to alter this behavior.

If you do not enable Peer-to-Peer transfers, then data transfers (e.g. `cudaMemcpy`, `cudaMemcpyAsync`, `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync`) between those two devices will flow from the source GPU over PCIE to the CPU socket, (perhaps traversing intermediate PCIE switches, perhaps also flowing over a socket-level link such as QPI) and then over PCIE from the CPU socket to the other GPU. At least one CPU socket will always be involved, even if a shorter direct path exists across the PCIE fabric.  This behavior is also not modifiable in any fashion available to the programmer.

Both methodologies are demonstrated using the `p2pBandwidthLatencyTest` CUDA sample code.

Comment: Any guidance on how to write a TensorFlow test using tensorflow.contrib.nccl.all_sum. "nvidia-smi nvlink -g 0 -i 0" didn't indicate any byte transfers.

Comment: Is there a way to disable P2P at the OS level, so that no app will use it? I do not have physical access to the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer -- from an NVIDIA employee -- was correct in 2018. But at some point, NVIDIA added an (undocumented?) option to the driver.

On Linux, you can now put this in /etc/modprobe.d/disable-nvlink.conf:

```
options nvidia NVreg_NvLinkDisable=1
```

This will disable NVLink when the driver is next loaded, forcing GPU peer-to-peer communication to use the PCIe interconnect. This gadget exists in driver 515.65.01 (CUDA 11.7.1). I am not sure when it was added.

As for ["there is no reason to allow the end-user to choose the slower path"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53174224/#comment93242873_53174224), the very existence of this SO question suggests otherwise. In my case, we buy not one server, but dozens... And in the process of choosing our configuration, it is nice to use a single prototype system to benchmark our application using either NVLink or PCIe.